# Want to use the array_filter function in foreach in php and whether it is a proper use or not

Tags: php

```
$arrvalue=['A','B','C','A','C','D','A','B'];
$findArr = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];
    $arrCount = []; 

    foreach ($findArr as $value) {
      $arr = array_filter($arrValue, function ($val) {
        return $val == $value;
      });
      array_push($arrCount, count($arr));
    }
```

I want to count how many times each of A, B, C, and D appear in the `$arrValue` array and put it in the `$arrCount` array. For example, something like this. [3,2,2,1]. However, the $value value is not recognized in the array_filter function. What's the problem?

Comment: `function ($val) use ($value) ...`

Comment: Besides the problem at hand, you should simply use this `array_count_values(['A','B','C','A','C','D','A','B']);`. ;)

Comment: Reason it php can't access it is because the anonymous function that you create/use in the array_filter, has it's own scope, one where it doesn't have access to the outside scope, aka $value